# WMI Exporter is giving error while trying to scrape metrics when we export metrics using text-file-collector

Tags: python, prometheus

**wmi_textfile_scrape_error 1 if there was an error opening or reading a file, 0 otherwise**

````
import pyodbc
import os
import sys
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=win-bk9m8;'
                      'Database=metric-db;'
                      'UID=sa;'
                      'PWD=password;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
count1 = cursor.execute("select count(*) from MissedEvents  where  TenantId > 10 and remarks like 'Mandatory%' AND RowCreatedDate >= dateadd(hh, -2, getdate())")
mandatory_items_missing_count = count1.fetchone()[0]
remarkname = "mandatory-items-missing"
#print(mandatory_items_missing_count)
print('# HELP missedevents_table_remarks {0}'.format(remarkname))    
print('# TYPE missedevents_table_remarks gauge' )
print('missedevents_table_remarks{{remark_type="{0}"}} {1}' .format(remarkname, mandatory_items_missing_count))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling debugging on wmi-exporter service, I came to know that error was due to unexpected end of input-stream; I have appended newline to above script and fixed the error.